# Operator ranking of sum and plus

Tags: sum

In the [book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) I am reading on page 308 I find the following formula:

[image]

My question is which operator has the higher rank - the sum or the plus? In other words: How would I correctly set the brackets in order to capture the above formula correctly, in way 1 or way 2?

Way 1:

[image: way1]

Way 2:

[image: way2]

Comment: I'd say that your first parentheses are correct, and that it wouldn't have been a bad idea for the author to show them.

Comment: There is no convention about this.  The meaning of such expressions must be inferred from the context.  If later on a term $|T|(\alpha|T|)$ appears, then $\alpha|T|$ is included in every term of the sum.  This seems unlikely: because $\alpha$ already is multiplied by $|T|,$ it would be a safe bet that $$C_\alpha(T)=\sum_{m=1}^{|T|}\left(N_mQ_m(T)+\alpha\right)=\left(\sum_{m=1}^{|T|}N_mQ_m(T)\right)+\alpha|T|.$$

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful to know.